# Define a default .properties file depending on language

Tags: java, properties

I have 2 `.properties` files in my java project and I want to define one of them as default file to be used when the language of the operating system is different from the 2 languages already defined.
Can you tell me please what should I add to my code to make that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ResourceBundle is your ticket. [Here is a tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Name the 2 .properties files by the same base name plus the language code, e.g.
prop_de.properties and prop_en.properties. Then copy one of them and name it prop.properties. This is the fallback. If the files are in package org.foo then

```
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle( "org.foo.prop" );
```

gives you a bundle with the behaviour you want.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for using one of the specified language files as default file without creating a new .properties file and copy the content to it. But I'll use that for the moment.
Thanks :-)